# What are the benefits of using multiple convolutions, as opposed to one, before the pooling layer in a U-Net?

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, generative-adversarial-networks, convolution, convolutional-layers, u-net

I have seen U-Nets that use a single convolution before the pooling operator and some that use two or more.

My question is, what is better? Or what are the benefits of using more or less convolutions?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Can you please provide links to these U-net versions that you're mentioning?